# pause timer until ajax completes

Tags: jquery, timer

I wrote the following timer function to check my database every x seconds... what I would like to do is pause the timer until the ajax completes and then once complete start it again.

Currently, it counts down to 0 from x seconds and when it reaches 0 the ajax check occurs.  The timer resets to x seconds as soon as 0 is reached and continues to run until it is stopped.

I am loading any number of images to the webpage with the ajax so it may take some time to load these ... which is the reason for the pause.

```
// start timer
$('#dtStart').on('click', function () {
    if(timerStatus != true) {
        var timerCount = $('#dtRefresh').val();
        $("#dtStart").addClass('hide');
        $("#dtStop").removeClass('hide');
    }

    function countdown(count) {             
        if(timerStatus != true) {
            timerStatus = true;
            timerId = setInterval(function() {
                count--;
                $("#dtTimer").html(count);
                if(count == 0) {
                    $("#dtTimer").html(count);
                    count = timerCount;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: '/process/p_realtime_screenshots.php',
                        data: { ss_id : $("#slider .slides-content:eq("+(slider.count - 1)+")").data('id') },
                        dataType : 'json'
                    }).done(function (response) {

                        if (response.success)
                        {                                   
                            //add new screenshots
                            $.each( response.screenshots, function( index, value )
                            {                                       
                                //add the slide
                                slider.addSlide('screenshot added here');                   

                                //correct the count
                                $(".slide-total-slides").text(" of "+slider.count);

                            });

                            //stop playing slider if it is and auto go to last slide added
                            $('#slider').flexslider("stop");
                            $('#slider').flexslider(slider.count - 1);

                        }

                    });

                }

            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    countdown(timerCount);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clearInterval()` to stop the timer at the beginning of the AJAX request and start it again on the `success` event:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    beforeSend:function(){ clearInterval(timerId);}
    success : function(){ /* Start timer again here  */}
    ...
});
```

Comment: I cannot find any information on beforeStart... is this the correct call?

Comment: Oops. . sorry it should be beforeSend. .